What makes a good Magento theme or frontend?
What are the factors that define the page speed/page-load of the Magento store? What are the things that we should be aware of?

Here is my 5 cents:

Hosting. Magento 2 needs resources, it won't run effectively on $10/mo shared plan.
Use as few 3rd-party extensions as possible. From my experience, poor performance in 99% cases comes from a poorly coded plugin.
Use code profiler to lower TTFB. Online PHP profilers like new relic, tideways etc could help lower time to first byte.
Use slightly modified Blank or Luma themes. Those themes are lightweight and pretty fast.
Utilize cache warmer. Write a simple script that warms full page cache of your site for optimal TTFB.

